# StepVerifier Redis infinite stream

Tags: redis, spring-webflux, junit5, spring-test, testcontainers

I'm using Redis Streams to create an infinite stream, then I created a method to listen new items on the stream. I want to test this method to make sure that after connecting to redis stream I will get new items on the stream.
I'm using spring-webflux, junit5 and test containers for redis.
Here is the test I made:

```java
@Autowired 
private ClassUnderTest template;

@SpyBean 
private ReactiveStringRedisTemplate reactiveStringRedisTemplate;

@Test
void streamFromLatest() {

    final ConfigurationRedis configRedis = ...;

    StepVerifier.create(template.streamFromLatest(streamKey))
        .expectNextCount(0)
        .then(
            () ->
                reactiveStringRedisTemplate
                    .opsForStream()
                    .add(StreamRecords.objectBacked(configRedis).withStreamKey(streamKey))
                    .block())
        .expectNext(configRedis)
        .thenCancel()
        .verify(Duration.ofSeconds(20));
}
```

When I run the test in Eclipse sometimes pass and sometimes fails, but when I run maven always fails.

Here is the method under test:

```java
private final StreamReceiver<String, MapRecord<String, String, String>> streamReceiver;

public Flux<ConfigurationRedis> streamFromLatest(@NotNull final String streamKey) {

    return streamReceiver
        .receive(StreamOffset.latest(streamKey))
        .doOnNext(value -> log.debug("New value on stream {}", value))
        .map(map -> mapper.map(map.getValue(), ConfigurationRedis.class))
        .doOnCancel(() -> log.debug("One of the consumers cancel"));
}
```

There is any way with StepVerifier of consistently add items to the stream after subscribing the `streamFromLatest` method?

Comment: cant you just mock `StreamReceiver#receive` or am i missing something here?

Comment: The purpose of my test is to connect to an actual redis instance, I'm using testcontainers for that.